# How to cut a part of a video to make two horizontal black bars on the top and bottom

Tags: video, premiere, video-editor

I wanted to remove a part of the video itself not removing a clip from it if you know what I mean, like making to horizontal black bars on the top and bottom or something similar I wonder if someone could tell me how.
I am using Adobe Premier Pro CC 2015.

Answer (score 1):

#### The specific effect you are referencing is [CROPPING](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cropping_(image)#Cropping_in_cinematography_&_broadcasting), which logically affects [ASPECT RATIO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio) in the context of [FILM FORMATS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_motion_picture_film_formats).

Along those lines, the "widescreen" format that many associate with cinematic imagery originally came from the use of anamorphic lenses (which resulted in a characteristic [anamorphic aspect ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anamorphic_format).

Anamorphic lenses impart more than just an aspect ratio to the image, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.  Nevertheless, because people have become used to viewing video in this "widescreen" format, it's become popular to clone this effect on YouTube videos etc.

---

If you are going to do this I would recommend changing your timeline aspect ratio rather than using a "crop bars" overlay on a normal 1080p ratio for example.

This is because people on widescreen monitors or mobile devices in landscape mode will be able to view the video using the screen's entire real estate. If you use the "crop bars" overlay then they will get a smaller image.

---

The 2.4:1 aspect ratio is a common widescreen format.  A 1920 x 800 timeline setting gives the anamorphic appearance nicely. (Using horizontal dimensions divisible by 8 or 16, which both 1920 and 800 are, make for more friendly encoding of macroblocks used by H.264 and H.265.)  On platforms like YouTube, the crop bars will automatically be added for normal 1080p display purposes.

Comment: The first section of your answer (re: anamorphic aspect ratio) is insightful and correct, but your elaboration is overstated.  Instead of saying "This is actually achieved ..." you could say "Anamorphic lenses combined with rectangular image frames tend to have aspect ratios ranging from 2:1 to 2.4:1 or more, and were widely associated with Widescreen formats.  Nowadays large image sensors allow 2.4:1 crops in camera (though that does not, by itself, provide other signatures of anamorphic lenses, such as oval bokeh or less depth of field."

Comment: The second part of your answer, about timeline aspect ratio is right on.

Comment: The 3rd part of your answer, the specific ratio 1920 x 803 is NOT good advice.  Many codecs perform best when horizontal and vertical resolutions are divisible by 8 or 16.  803 is not such a number.  A 2.4:1 aspect ratio for 1920W gives 800H.  800 is a very, very evenly divisible number.

Comment: @MichaelTiemann thanks for the feedback - I wasn't aware of codecs performing better on divisble numbers (still learning) I just opened up an old project to see what the size was (I may have even extended the height in error somehow). I did begin to go into more detail in the first part when I was typing my answer but found myself waffling. Your explanation would be much more succint and relevant. (Happy for you to edit my answer and mark as wiki?)

Comment: It's not even a matter of performance. H.264 *can't* encode videos with odd numbers of pixels. Many encoders will silently add or subtract a row to cope with this.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of YouTube videos on how to do this and various different ways, such as cropping the top and bottom, or using a PNG image to the correct format you want to show, you could also even make the timeline the aspect ratio you want to use and expand the image up to fill the area.

Answer (score 0):

In adobe Premier CC if you go to the effects panel and search for crop you can add the effect to your clip and then control how much you want to crop from the top and the bottom i usually set mine to 11% top and bottom.